# What is the meaning of spread in "...a nice charcuterie spread and a healthy selection of vegetables"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is the meaning of ***'spread'*** in the following sentence:

> Here we’ve provided a nice charcuterie ***spread*** and a healthy selection of vegetables.

Comment: The term "cold cuts" is far more common than "charcuteries".  Even my spell-checker does not recognize "charcuterie".

Comment: @Jasper: That really depends on where you are: "charcuterie" is seen/heard far more often than "cold cuts" in British English.

Comment: @Jasper, I disagree as a BrEng speaker; I would wonder what "cold cuts" meant without context. I'm familiar with the term charcuterie however, though I'd probably use "cold meats" or "deli meats" more readily

Comment: Indeed, my spell checker does **not** mark charcuterie as misspelled.

Comment: (BrEng here)  Cold cuts sounds American, and *to me* excludes cured meats (Jamón, air-dried sausages etc.) which might be suggested by the more continental *charcuterie* (no --s, it's a mass noun already execpt in the sense of the shop).

Comment: @LukeH, James, and Chris:  Thanks for the tip on British English.  I do not remember ever seeing the word "charcuterie" before -- not even when studying for spelling bees.  The weird thing is, the quote is from a page written in American English, complete with "neighbor" (not "neighbour"), a New York author, and a California contact address.

Comment: @Jasper: I guess some Americans are more willing than others to throw French loan-words into the mix. I can't imagine Frasier Crane passing up an opportunity to say "charcuterie", or Martin Crane neglecting to object and mock him for it.

Comment: I never saw the word *charcuterie* in American English until a few years ago, but since then I've seen it more and more.  For instance, any moderately fancy restaurant in the US that offers a plate of cold cured meat now seems to list it on the menu as *charcuterie*.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBxWYVBCOZo

Answer (score 18):

Probably sense 30 of spread [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spread):

> *Informal.* an abundance of food set out on a table; feast.

Comment: Wow. I saw this question and thought "well, the answer should be easily found in a dictionary". But when it's definition number 30, I now understand the difficulty in finding the answer!

Comment: I think this definition sounds good to me. It allows me to think of "large meal", "a variety of foods", and/or "food spreads on a table". Here is a similar definition given by another dictionary: **[spread](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/spread_2#spread_2__8)**  [informal] a large meal with a lot of different dishes to choose from.

Answer (score 5):

charcuterie means [*cooked meats*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/charcuterie) and *spread* refers to [well prepared food to be enjoyed](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=spread).

The [original paragraph](http://vision.cloudera.com/how-do-you-host-a-tech-meetup/) talks about how one hosts a tech meetup. Reading the paragraph, we can relate 'enjoyable and tasty food' to avoid the distraction of those hungry people!

> No one should go hungry, least of all when they’re in your care as a meetup host. The golden hour for most meetups is right after work and ends well past dinnertime. ***Hungry people are easily distracted***, so *maintaining interest* goes hand in hand with keeping appetites satisfied. Here we’ve provided a nice charcuterie spread and a healthy selection of vegetables. Trays of small, non-messy snacks are perfect for sharing with strangers while socializing.

Answer (score 4):

I always associated 'spread' with a large selection distributed so that it takes up an impressive amount of space on the table. So pretty much 'spread out' on the table.

Answer (score 0):

`charcuterie spread` could alsos be the tentative English translation of the French `pâté` : ["Pâté (UK /ˈpæteɪ/ or US /pɑːˈteɪ/; French pronunciation: ​[pɑte]) is a mixture of cooked ground meat and fat minced into a **spreadable** paste"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A2t%C3%A9)

Comment: I don't think in this context that they're talking about a spread in the sense of a spreadable paste, but rather "an abundant meal laid out on a table". Here's an example http://bakerbynature.com/summertime-cheese-charcuterie-spread/

Comment: you are certainly right. Just wanted to add another idea

Comment: Oh, I see - maybe some explanation of what a "spread" is in that sense would make it clear you're illustrating a different sense of the word. I guess we could probably rule out a coverlet made of meat though ;)

Comment: @ColleenV See also the last sentence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_(food) However I agree that in this case the author would probably have said "meat spread" rather than "charcuterie spread". Technically, a pate (or a meat spread) is a charcuterie itself

Comment: I was suggesting a little more elaboration for the learners that will be reading your answer, not for me :)